# Python functions vs Cpython command implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, contextmanager

In which contexts is useful to implement new commands such as a possible `ignored [Excepions]` instead of defining them as functions?

**'ignored' contextmanager:**

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def ignored(*exceptions):
    try:
        yield
    except exceptions:
        pass
```

**Usage:**

```
with ignored(IndexError, KeyError):
    ## inside code here
```

**Possible alternative:**

```
ignored IndexError, KeyError:
    ## inside code here
```

Comment: How were you going to implement the alternative? Are you planning on updating the python parser?

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah, I'd want to know your opinions about advantages and disadvantages...

Comment: Fiddling with the python parser is difficult and then you end up with a non-standard interpreter that will likely have little uptake. Besides a toy implementation you use for practice I see no benefit to doing it. If you like the challenge, go for it, but I wouldn't call it useful to others!

Answer (score -1):

It just makes things a lot cleaner.

Checkout these two implementations

```
with file("/tmp/foo", "w") as foo:
    print >> foo, "Hello!"
```

This is essentially equivalent to:

```
foo = file("/tmp/foo", "w")
try:
    print >> foo, "Hello!"
finally:
    foo.close()
```

But which would you rather use!

Check out [this](http://eigenhombre.com/2013/04/20/introduction-to-context-managers/) for further reading

Comment: Ah okay. I'd take @tdelaney comment then. That sums it up well!